# Compute the time when one person is standing still in front of camera

Tags: opencv

Our App will play videos on its screen and someone will watch the videos. And there is one camera on its screen that will capture face of the people who watching video. I'm using Open CV to detect face, gender, age range. And I already finished them.

And i have another task that is computing the time of one person in front of camera. That basically means if one person (A) stands in front of camera from 09:00 AM to 09:30 AM to watch videos, I can calculate that A spend 30 minutes for watching videos.

What I want is calculating the time period of any people watching videos? If a person was watching my videos from 8:10:00 AM to 8:15:15 AM, What I want is the time period, in this case It's 8:10:00 AM - 8:15:15 AM. Can I use Open CV to get these values?

Could you please help me? Where can i find document about this thing? Or give me some opinions about what i should do.

Maybe my English is not good. So I'm really sorry about that. Hope you help me.

Comment: Can you add few snaps to better understand situation and type of detection you may need.

Comment: Is your question about time measurement or about person detection? Or is your question about detecting whether a detected person stands still (= watches videos) in front of the camera? Which parts did you finish already and which parts are open?

Comment: What I want is about the time measurement. Actually, our app will play advertising videos on screen in supermarket or somewhere. If our App is playing a video which has 20 seconds. And there are two people watching the video from second 5 to second 13. the important is determining that is the same person standing still and watching the video during second 5 to second 13. Finally, the result i want is there are two people watching the video from second 5 to second 13. Just the format like this: obj.start = 5; obj.end = 13; obj.people = 2; I want this obj. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        there few steps i actually have in my mind:
        1: Take the picture of new person at the time of capture timer start 
        2: match the pic with the current user watching video, At the point where match not found stop the timer calculate the time capture the image of new user and start the timer of new person

        So If person A come to see the video u capture his face and timer start he stay 5 seconds and leave the next frame in which face of A not found Timer stops and calculate the time in the same period detect the other face in the image if face found start the procedure of time again 

        This Work if U have no Database of images of user watching the video.....
    But if U have the images let me Thanks
I hope this will help u
```